# Visual Studio WebPart to get the item being edited to replace List Edit Form

Tags: visual-studio, visual-web-part

I had created a web part in Visual Studio 2010 for Sharepoint 2010. I added all the fields, implemented cascading dropdowns, custom panel and bind the data using Sharepoint SPLists

```
            var collection = mysite.Lists;

            SPListItemCollection valList = mysite.Lists["MyValidationList"].Items;

            ddlCompanyName.DataSource = valList.GetDataTable();

            ddlCompanyName.DataTextField = "Title";

            ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
```

The problem is how to handle the submit buttons.

Like after i click the submit button i want to redirect to the lists page.

Similarly how can i create the edit form like how do i know which record is being modified

Can i use querystring..

Any help is appreciated.

Please note i am not using any third party library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the url its:

```
string url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/" + mysite.Lists["MyValidationList"].RootFolder.Url;
```

add the above to the button url,

as an example im creating a button and adding the url to the button click event:

**METHOD 1**
within create child controls

```
string url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/" + mysite.Lists["MyValidationList"].RootFolder.Url;

Button b = new Button();
b.PostBackUrl = url;
controls.add(b);
```

this method is assigning the url on the creation of the button.

**METHOD 2**

create a global varible to hold the url:

```
string url = null;
```

create your button within `creatchildcontrols` event:

```
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
        url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/" + mysite.Lists["MyValidationList"].RootFolder.Url;
        controls.add(b);
```

now we have created a button and a click event you want to populate the url you can do like so:

```
    private void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        b.PostBackUrl = url;
    }
```

this method is assigning the url on the click event of the button.

Comment: Thats great but can you please tell me the other part of the question that how to replace the existing/default forms for edit and create with my new webparts and how to get the record being edited. I cannot find any documentation for them

Comment: when you say edit form, you mean you want to change the default edit form when editing a list item and you want to replace it with your webpart?

Comment: Yes thats correct but all the sample i find out show steps to create a application page etc etc but then dont show how can i use my custom buttons etc. My Webpart is doing all the work itself and is not required any other facility. What i am unsure is that what will happen to the Save etc button that are in ribbon and how can i update the item being edited. I am using Sharepoint 2013

Comment: Similarly while saving the record i am using  SPListItem item = null;//valList[(Guid)]; But i am not able to find the Guid. How can i get this? While filling the form i am using .GetDataTable() and then using Select command